# Using 10.8 Notification Center in Java

Tags: java, macos, notifications, osx-mountain-lion

this is just a general question. I'm not having an actual project or something else where I want to do this.
Is it possible to build an App in Java and add some framework stuff or something else and use Notication Center?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wrote a simple `C` -> `Objective-C` shim .dylib that exported a function `showNotification` That delivered a notification immediately.

Then I wrote a [`JNA`](https://github.com/twall/jna) wrapper to the function exported in the dylib. I'm sure that you could use a combination of [Rococoa](https://code.google.com/p/rococoa/) and [JNAerator](http://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/) to eliminate this dylib altogether.

Then I wrote a simple java application that I turned into an [app bundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html). This is the important point. If your java application is not in an app bundle then notifications will not be delivered.

Messages delivered to the notification center.

[image: Screenshot of delivered notification]

It's eminently doable, you just have to play along with the rules of the `NSUserNotificationCenter` - **it must be in an app bundle**.

I used java 7, update 9 for this. [Another question seems to have had even more success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638092/using-os-x-10-8-notification-center-nsusernotification-with-java).

The code used to build this simple application is [available on github](https://github.com/petesh/OSxNotificationCenter). It contains an xcode project for creating the `.dylib`, and a netbeans project that makes use of the `.dylib` to deliver notifications.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a link to the relevant code. It's not complicated in the least and is only intended as sample code.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14698543) for how to send notifications without an app bundle.

Answer (score 12):

I' ve found a solution that might work for you, you can use `Apple script` to show notifications on osx, try this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "osascript", "-e", "display notification "This is a message" with title "Title" subtitle "Subtitle" sound name "Funk"" });
```

You can read about `Apple script`'s notifications in [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW224)

Comment: This is actually the most simple way i found to do this, works on el capitan without an app bundle for me

Comment: This just works. Excellent solution!

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution will be Growl when the App will be updated to Growl 2.0 which will forward Growl Notifications to the Notification Center.

Informations about [Growl 2](http://growl.posterous.com/growl-2-and-hardwaregrowler-2-both-in-beta)

Growl Messages can be forwarded with the current Versions by using [MoutainGrowl](https://github.com/stigi/MountainGrowl/)

Growl can be used under Java with [libgrowl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libgrowl/) or [jgntp](http://code.google.com/p/jgntp/)

Maybe it's not the cleanest solution and it has some requirements to the user but it's definitely one that works

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you take a look at how IntelliJ IDEA handles notifications in [MountainLionNotifications](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/ui/MountainLionNotifications.java) and [GrowlNotifications](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/ui/GrowlNotifications.java).

As suggested in other answers, it uses JNA to manipulate NSObjects.