# How to create pop-up desktop notifications in MacOS using java?

Tags: java, macos

[image]I am now working on a java project which needs to create a pop-up notification, similar to the one shown in the picture. For Windows, SystemTray could be used, but for Mac OS it doesn't show the notification globally. How could I achieve this? Is there any specific libraries I need to use?

Comment: Similar but apparently outdated Questions: [*OSX Notification System for Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27372524/642706), [*Using 10.8 Notification Center in Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11720652/642706), [*Using OS X 10.8 Notification Center (NSUserNotification) with Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13638092/642706), and [*Mac OS Push Notifications with Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53153578/642706).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this experience before. It is better to use a more suitable library like [two-slices](https://github.com/sshtools/two-slices) instead of Java Swing, which is cross platform and works the same in all operating systems. Your code should be such that you can display the icon and message in the System Tray

```
Toast.toast(ToastType.INFO, "Information", "Here is some information you cannot do without.");
```

Comment: Is there any more alternative libraries?

Comment: yes, for example you can use notify in https://github.com/dorkbox/Notify