# Can I use Mountain Lion's Notification Center from Java?

Tags: java, macos, user-interface, notifications, integration

Our application currently uses an in-house solution for notifications. We use some transparent frames and a little bit of animation.

However, for the next version, we plan to implement more *native* notifications on Windows and OS X.

Is there any way I can send notifications to the notification center from a Java application?

The Java app will be using a bundled version of Java 7, and not the default Apple-supplied JVM, as it's still at 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Notification Center via JNA. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720652/using-10-8-notification-center-in-java) provides a pretty good discussion. Essentially, you create a .dylib to wrap each native method, create a Java interface for the .dylib, and access the .dylib via JNA.

In my solution, I was successful in wrapping and using every method in the [NSUserNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSUserNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could integrate with Growl (growl.info) using one of the Java bindings available.