# OSX Notification System for Java

Tags: java, macos, swing, notifications

I have spent numerous hours researching and attempting to find a viable solution for creating system notifications on the Mac OSX Operating System. Out of all of the solutions here is what I have concluded:

- [Twinkle](http://www.swingfx.ch/) - It appears to be the most efficient tool when creating notifications however there is a significant lack of documentation, large amounts of outdated documentation links, and is confusing to use.
- [Growl](http://growl.info/) - This is most likely the best solution for anybody else but requires a separate installation on the machine. Furthermore, it is a paid solution which for most pieces of software is not scalable nor distributable.
- Apple Script - I find this the most intuitive and simplistic solution of the three with the pros of it being free and well documented. Consequently, several features lack in its function such as not being able to set the icon, or set what application the notification will refer to. Ex `display notification "Hello, world"`

While all solutions do make a notification on the Mac OSX machine, none of them can be packaged into the Jar, don't require a separate installation, are free and are up to date. Essentially if someone can create a tool that will make a MacOSX notification via some form of reflection to Objective-C that would be phenomenal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Using 10.8 Notification Center in Java*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11720652/261156).

Comment: I do not find the answer on that post to be adequate. Maybe I am not  looking at it well enough but there is no documentation on how you implement that GitHub lib into your project.

Comment: How are you deploying? I think you can specify the `.dylib` in a [tag:java-web-start] .jnlp` file, and I'm sure you can load it from an application bundle.