# Mac OS Push Notifications with Java

Tags: java, objective-c, macos

I want to have push notifications in Mac OS style in my JavaFX project, which turned out to be actually really difficult.

I was following the approach described in the accepted answer on:
[Using 10.8 Notification Center in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720652/using-10-8-notification-center-in-java)

I cloned the linked [github repo](https://github.com/petesh/OSxNotificationCenter). From the Xcode project I exported the *.dylib* file and moved it to */usr/local/lib*.
I took over the java interface to my project.

```
interface NsUserNotificationsBridge extends Library {
    NsUserNotificationsBridge instance = (NsUserNotificationsBridge)
            Native.loadLibrary("/usr/local/lib/NsUserNotificationsBridge.dylib", NsUserNotificationsBridge.class);

    public int sendNotification(String title, String subtitle, String text, int timeoffset);
}
```

Using `INsUserNotificationsBridge.instance.sendNotification(params...)` I am now able to send push notifications!

[image: MacOS Notification when running my project with IntelliJ]

This even works when running straight from the IDE (IntelliJ). In contradiction to the author's note that

> If your java application is not in an app bundle then notifications
>   will not be delivered.

That wonders me already. I build a single JAR artifact. Running the jar: everything is fine, the push notification is showing. Bundling it into an app: All fine, but no push notification! Also no error. So the very opposite of what the author wrote happened!

(See my [Info.plist](https://pastebin.com/XcQf02ri))

What did I do wrong? Why is it not showing when starting as .app? Is there maybe meanwhile an even better way to do MacOS push notifications with java? I already know about the way of executing an applescript but I don't like its behavior.

I'm on Java 9 btw.

Comment: Ever figured this out?