# How to show the NSUserNotification in command-line-tool program?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, notifications, apple-push-notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I want to write a command-line-tool program that only shows the NSUserNotification. I've found out, that in order to show the NSUserNotification I need to create a Cocoa App and is not what I want.

I want to run my program at log-in in background, so that my notification is always visible. How can I do that without creating a Cocoa App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the options I found...

- [Trick Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712535/mac-mountain-lion-send-notification-from-cli-app) into allowing a notification from a command-line tool.
- Trigger the notification using [Applescript or a helper application](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-center-notification-from-an-applescript-or-shel).
- Create an `Automator` workflow & execute it using the [`automator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/automator.1.html) command.

`Automator` provides a better experience than `Applescript`. Didn't try the helper.